# How can I find out if IBM will be releasing new versions of the iOS SDK for Swift?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am very interested in using BlueMix for mobile development.  Really interested.

I've created a couple of stub app's using iOS9+ and Swift.  And I can see that there is real potential.

My question is.  When I look at the educational materials and toolkits available I get the impression that IBM are no longer investing in this area.  How can I be sure that BlueMix and Mobile will receive investment?  How can I be sure that BlueMix will support future versions of iOS?

I know some might think this is too general a question.  The problem I have is that IBM is such a huge company I have no idea who I can approach for an answer directly.

Comment: For questions regarding Bluemix offerings and your Bluemix account, you can post at IBM developerWorks Answers (developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html) and/or open a Bluemix support ticket from the Account and Support widget at the upper right corner of the Bluemix dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention this is certainly not a technical question. That said, if you would like reassurance that the mobile SDKs (including Swift) are a major focus feel free to monitor the [Bluemix Mobile Services public-facing Github](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services) where you will see daily activity as work is done to bring all the BMS SDKs up to the latest and greatest releases for the iOS, Android, and Hybrid platforms.

Comment: Yes - @James, you are right.  Just recently there has been some activity in this GitHub area.  Unfortunately most of if was creating empty repositories holding a readme and maybe a licence.  There are a couple of Swift examples in there, I think the latest update on those examples was +4 months ago.

The key repo' I saw there is called "BMS Client SDK Swift Core" - this got me all excited.  Allas... just a holding repo with no content.  I am watching that repo' so I will wait fingers crossed.
https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-swift-core

Comment: There's nothing in the master branch because nothing has been officially released yet for those samples and SDKs. You can see daily activity in the development and other branches.